# how to make the last row of a table fill the remaining space down

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I am trying to have the last row of a table fill out the remaining space of a page (vertically). I came up with a solution, but it only works properly on chrome and safari but doesn't work on FF.
In my project I am using a material design table, but it is not relevant to this question, i think.
He's what I was trying to do that worked in chrome, but didn't in FF.
I'd love to hear some suggestions on how to make this work also on that browser.
Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/2ex1Lp9n/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner_fixed {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.inner_remaining {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mytab {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_fixed">
    I have a fixed height
  </div>

  <div class="inner_remaining">
    <table class="mytab">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            hello
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            la la la
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your table contain tabular data? You may want to reconsider using it as a primary layout mechanism. It's not ideal, as you've learned.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, tested in Chrome, FF, and Edge. In order for an element to have 100% height, its parent must also have a similar height. Once that is done, then it's just a matter of targeting the cells in the last row.

```css
html,
body {
  /* parent must have height 100% */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  /* table must be 100% */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.table td {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 8px;
}

/* target cells in last row */
.table tr:last-child td {
  height: 100%;
}

/* for display only */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #fefefe;
  text-align: left;
}
.spacer {
  height: 400px;
  background: slategray;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        TABLE HEADER
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        TABLE CELL
      </td>
      <td>
        TABLE CELL
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        TABLE CELL
      </td>
      <td>
        TABLE CELL
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        TABLE CELL
      </td>
      <td>
        TABLE CELL
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="spacer">SPACER</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a makeshift solution for it, not a perfect one but will work.

**Make last row height as 100% and hide scroll of body(container to which scroll is getting added in this example):**

```
<tr height="100%">
```

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner_fixed {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.inner_remaining {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mytab {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_fixed">
    I have a fixed height
  </div>

  <div class="inner_remaining">
    <table class="mytab">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            hello
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr height="100%">
          <td>
            la la la
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PS:** I tried flex inside table but it was causing tr width and height being adjusted to content. Hence, above solution is the best I could come of

Comment: I think this is much better than trying to hammer flexbox onto a table anyway. Nice.

Comment: Yes internally lot much going on to set dimesions of table and its content.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding:

```
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
```

to the class

```
  inner_remaining
```

Comment: Have _you_ tried it? Does it work? I suggest that you copy the snippet from above and try, then we'll both know. :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use **colspan** which merge two columns

```css
 html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
} 
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner_fixed {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.inner_remaining {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  flex-grow : 1;
}
.mytab {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td,th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The td colspan attribute</h1>
 <div class="inner_fixed">
    I have a fixed height
  </div>
<div class="inner_remaining">
      <table class="mytab">
      
  <tr>
    <th colspan='2'>Month</th>
    
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">La la al</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am not sure how this helps :(

Comment: the problem i want to solve is make the last row extend vertically to fill the empty space down. in FF what happens is that the table grows evenly (all rows, including header), but i want just the last row, like chrome does